# Samba, Windows ACLs and unwanted executable bit

Tags: access-control-list, samba4

I setup [Samba with ACL support](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs) on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server and I'm facing the following situation.

Here's the `smb.conf` content:

```
[global]
   # naming
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

   # networking
   disable netbios = yes
   local master = no
   domain master = no
   preferred master = no

   # domain accounts
   security = ADS
   realm = EXAMPLE.COM
   encrypt passwords = yes
   invalid users = root

   idmap config *:backend = tdb
   idmap config *:range = 70001-80000

   template shell = /bin/bash

   winbind nss info = rfc2307
   winbind use default domain = yes
   winbind rpc only = yes
   winbind cache time = 10

   vfs objects = acl_xattr
   map acl inherit = yes
   acl group control = yes
   store dos attributes = no

   # logging
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000

   # permissions
   create mode = 0644
   directory mode = 0755
   inherit acls = yes
   map archive = no

   # printers
   load printers = no

   # veto files
   veto files = /._*/.DS_Store/

[All Users]
   comment = All Home Directories
   path = /home/EXAMPLE
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   valid users = @dl_acc_ro @dl_acc_rw
```

From macOS Sierra, I connect to a samba share with `smb://myserver.com/test`. Then I open a terminal and `$ cd /Volumes/test` and I finally create a file with `$ touch xxx`.

Here's the output of `$ ls -l` on my Mac:

```
$ ls -l
-rwx------  1 gregory  staff  0 Sep 26 20:00 xxx
```

And now on the server itself:

```
$ ls -l
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 gregory utilisa. du domaine 0 Sep 26 18:00 xxx
```

And ACLs:

```
$ getfacl /home/EXAMPLE/gregory
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/EXAMPLE/gregory
# owner: gregory
# group: utilisa.\040du\040domaine
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x


$ getfacl /home/EXAMPLE/gregory/xxx
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/EXAMPLE/gregory/xxx
# owner: gregory
# group: utilisa.\040du\040domaine
user::rwx
user:gregory:rwx
group::r-x
group:utilisa.\040du\040domaine:r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

As you can see, the regular file created by `touch` has the executable bit set. Is there a way I can avoid this behavior? I would like regular files created through Samba to have `0644` permissions.

For the record, I tested from a Linux workstation and it exhibits the same behavior, which makes me believe it's all happening on the Samba server side.

Comment: The only thing suspicious to me in your config : "inherit_acls = y" ; "map acl inherit = y"

Comment: Removing them don't help unfortunately :(

Answer (score 6):

From the [Samba manual:](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html)

> Consequently, there is no use for any of the three Unix executable
>   bits that are present on a file in a Samba disk share. DOS files,
>   however, have their own attributes that need to be preserved when they
>   are stored in a Unix environment: the archive, system, and hidden
>   bits. Samba can preserve these bits by reusing the executable
>   permission bits of the file on the Unix side—if it is instructed to do
>   so. Mapping these bits, however, has an unfortunate side effect: if a
>   Windows user stores a file in a Samba share, and you view it on Unix
>   with the ls -al command, some of the executable bits won't mean what
>   you'd expect them to.

How to disable it? Following from the manual:

> Three Samba options decide whether the bits are mapped: map archive,
>   map system , and map hidden. These options map the archive, system,
>   and hidden attributes to the owner, group, and world execute bits of
>   the file, respectively. You can add these options to the [data] share,
>   setting each of their values as follows:

```
 [data]
    map archive = no
    map system = no
    map hidden = no
```

You call also disable the executable bit by using the [`store dos attributes`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#MAPARCHIVE) flag.

Comment: I don't see how `map archive = yes` solves it. My understanding is that I need `map archive = no` which I use. `map system` and `map hidden` are set to `no` by default. All of these I read them. They don't apply when using `vfs objects = acl_xattr` unfortunately

Comment: You should set all these attributes as **no**. You can also try setting the `store dos attribute = yes` flag.

Comment: I tried with `store dos attribute = yes` but it doesn't help at all

Comment: And I swear your initial answer said `map archive = yes` :(

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the various `mask` settings in `smb.conf`. E.g. `create mask`, `directory mask`, ...

Furthere these `masks` can be influenced by the mount options on the client, which can also be helpful to look at the details.